# Перевод слова: нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такое: "гранит (от латинского granum - зерно)..." Так вот, нужно ли оба эти слова "granum" и "зерно" в данном случае брать в кавычки?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не нужно. На латинице однозначно не берётся, на русском возможно с кавычками(для заострения внимания на том, что это значение слова),но чаще пишется без кавычек, это же слово, его значение не особое, а прямое, обыденное.